# Flask tag questions barely get an answer on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

These days I'm learning new programming technologies & languages but I've noticed despite the fact many websites talk about these new languages and make tutorials for them, many questions about these languages remain unanswered on Stack Overflow. Picking the wrong technology is a waste of time for me and many others just like me.

Is there a way to estimate how active is the community around these new technologies?

Comment: Look at the tag statistics. Play with the data explorer...

Comment: what is tag statics ?

Comment: @CameronA statistics ;) % unanswered, number of questions/answers. That type of deal

Comment: I agree.  Where's my flask...

Comment: @rene http://stackoverflow.com/tags/flask/topusers has the statistics

Comment: @Will you have had enough for today, get sober will you ...

Comment: There's only a few active users in the tag, but we answer pretty much every well asked / interesting question that we have the time to.  The problem is mostly that there's a constant flood of low quality stuff.  The community is certainly active.

Comment: Back in my day, we would pick technologies based on factors other than whether you'd get answers on Stack Overflow for them. [*shakes cane*](https://a1-images.myspacecdn.com/images03/3/f9521998f1d14bbd82c43fe7c26a0f1c/600x600.jpg)

Comment: 38% of the questions in [flask] got an answer last week.  Not great, not drastically worse than main stream libraries like [django] (44%) or [jquery] (42%).  Being "new" doesn't qualify it to get more answers, rather the opposite since fewer SO users will be familiar with it.  The drastic mismatch between the number of users that ask for help and the number that want to provide that help is the larger problem.  Contributing answers is an *excellent* way to get to learn the nitty-gritty of a [tag] subject, obvious opportunities in [flask].

Comment: Thank you guys, this was my first meta question I really dont know about the guidelines of asking question here, so Accept my apology for inappropriate question

Comment: Voting on meta is different: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta  people down vote here to voice disagreement